# What is the ^I character and how do I find it with sed?

Tags: vim, text-editing, sed, escape-characters

I usually import data from csv files to MySQL, but my data provider leaves NULL entries as "", so I need to replace "" with "\N". This is easy enough with a script like

```
for csvfile in *.csv
do
    sed -i -e 's/^,/\\N,/' -e 's/,$/,\\N/' -e 's/,,/,\\N,/g' -e 's/,,/,\\N,/g' $csvfile
done
```

However, I have a csv file with commas, so the import fails. I got the file as "tab delimited" and tried

```
for txtfile in *.txt
do
    sed -i -e 's/^\\t/\\N\\t/' -e 's/\\t$/\\t\\N/' -e 's/\\t\\t/\\t\\N\\t/g' -e 's/\\t\\t/\\t\\N\\t/g' $txtfile
done
```

But it still fails (as far as I can tell, the script doesn't add any "\N"). When I open the tab-delimited file in Vim and type `:set list` it looks like tabs are stored instead as "^I". I tried replacing "\t" with "\^I", but doesn't add the "\N" NULL characters that I need.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an answer for what the ^Is are, but one reason your second `sed` command fails is that you're using the wrong sequence for matching a tab. The sequence that matches a tab is `\t`, not `\\t`.  `\\t` matches a `\` followed by a `t`.

Comment: Makes sense. I am confusing wanting an explicit "\N", which I add with "\\N", with looking for the tab. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

^ is normally shorthand for Ctrl and Ctrl-I is the same as Tab

Comment: Do you know how I can make my `sed` work? I tried replacing "\\t" with "\^I" but it didn't work?